# Get page source of a web page running in the emulator while the script used is running in the local machine?

Tags: android, emulation, html, monkeyrunner

Here's what I need to do,

1. I need to get the page source of a web page running inside the emulator.
2. The script that is going to perform the task is running in the local machine.
3. The script is made using monkeryrunner.

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a blog post I read about this just the other day:

http://dtmilano.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/androidviewclient-getting-browsers-html.html

I believe it will only run in the emulator but you have that in your tags so it is likely this will do exactly what you want!